# Output this into JSON Format for use in elasticsearch?

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch, word-frequency

I have a python code which finds the words and their frequency which are present in the base file. Here is the code

```
import os
import re
import sys

d=[]

with open("all_words_to_find.txt") as f:
    d = map(str.rstrip, f.readlines())

file_name = sys.argv[1]
fp =open(file_name,"r")

word_count ={}

found = []
for line in fp:
    for word in d:
        if word in line:
            found.append(word)

#print(found)
fo = []

for val in found:
    va = val.rstrip()
    fo.append(va)

#print fo

with open('output.txt','w') as fp:
    for value in [ele for ind, ele in enumerate(fo,1) if ele not in fo[ind:]]:
        fp.write("{} : {} \n".format(value,fo.count(value)))
```

This gives the output as:

```
word1 : 3
word2 : 4
```

And I want the output as:

```
que = {
     "query": {
         "bool": {
            "must": [
                { "match": {
                    "section": {
                        "query": "word1",
                        "boost": 3
                    },
                    "section": {
                        "query" : "word2",
                        "boost" : 4
                    }
                }}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this, Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Although i am not quite sure what you want to achieve with the query and the query mentioned here is not correct. But my assumption is that you want something like this

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "match": {
                    "section": {
                        "query": "word1",
                        "boost": "3"
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "match": {
                    "section": {
                        "query": "word2",
                        "boost": "4"
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}

import json

def convert_to_es_query(file):
    basequery = {}
    bool_query = {}
    must_query = []
    bool_query["bool"] = {"must": must_query}
    basequery["query"] = bool_query
    with open(file) as f:
        for line in f:
            word, boost = line.split(':')
            must_query.append({"match": {"section": {"query": word.strip(), 
"boost": boost.strip()}}})

    return json.dumps(basequery)
```

Although i would suggest the best way to achieve something like this is by using search templates....they are just awesome. But since i wasn't quite sure about your elasticsearch query so couldn't formulate one template. But you can take a look at this one https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-template.html.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have one question: How to use "OR" in between the "match" ?

Comment: go for "should" instead of "must" then take a look at this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html